# How to bypass blocked port "53" to use openvpn at office in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, vpn, openvpn

I've the following problem:

I've an VPN provider which only provides ports 53,5100 to use with openvpn. But I think the wifi at my office blocks these ports. So is there any possibility to change it that way, that I maybe can use port 443 for openvpnconnection which seems to be open. I hope my problem is getting clear. If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you try using port 5100?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Please contact the VPN provider and/or the administrator of your local network.

Comment: @dennis605 - did you managed to use port 5100?

Comment: @Yaron - no unfortunately not. It seems to be blocked, too.

Answer (score 6):

> Due to the unclear nature of the original question, it was assumed this is a workplace network.  The second section underneath the horizontal rule covers the 'nearby open wifi' part.  The rest of the question is kept for historical reasons.

There's a few things here in your question that raise a few red flags, so I'm going to outline these.  Point #3 is the answer to your question.

1. **You are trying to use a VPN from within your workplace's network**, likely to bypass some type of controls in place on the network.  This is *very likely* a violation of the IT policies in your workplace, and you are more likely than not going to get in trouble for this, if not immediately fired due to the policies in place regarding proper network usage.
2. **Most workplace networks are configured to block internal-to-external traffic at the edge firewalls for the network**, with individual exceptions as needed for specific cases, or set up such that your traffic has to pass through certain control devices which are permitted to go external as they are gateways. (internal DNS servers, email or web gateways to filter content, etc.)
3. **You will need to contact your workplace IT people to discuss why you need the VPN, or whether this is against policy, because they control your network**.  There is no Ubuntu-specific way to 'bypass' security controls on networks when these kinds of policies are enforced, short of connecting to a different network that isn't as stringent with controls.  However, if this is a work computer, you'd be immediately exposing that system's data to threat actors, which is a no-no in most corporate network environments.

---

3. (revised) **You are using an 'open' wifi nearby your workplace** but you can't control what they do or don't filter.  There's no way to bypass these controls, unfortunately, except to use *another* network.  If that is not an option, then I believe it is impossible for you to bypass and get VPN access.  Normally, though, OpenVPN doesn't need port 53, it should *only* need whatever VPN server port it needs for the tunnel, and more than likely, you wouldn't be having port 53 'blocked' even in an open wifi situation.

I'd start looking at potential misconfigurations on your local machine that would interfere with port 53 and such.  Note that with my OpenVPN on 16.04+, I had to disable the resolver in SystemD, and configure NetworkManager to use `dnsmasq` instead to allow "remote" VPN DNS configurations to be accepted (though, due to other reasons, I now have a local DNS resolver that I use instead of `dnsmasq` and override everything at the `resolvconf` level to use that `bind9` resolver on my own system).

If this is a 'work' machine, though, you need to coordinate with your workplace IT team to see if this is acceptable - using a work machine on an open network *may* be considered a policy breach.

Comment: To clarify point #1 -- many work places with the kind of controls described also have a policy allowing immediate termination for bypassing those controls.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your reply. It's a liitle bit complicated. I should have mentioned that it's a open wifi near my office i'm trying togo through  . So I can't speak with someone from IT. But thanks for your reply.

Comment: @dennis605 Then your options are even *less* than these.  You ultimately would be trying to bypass whatever content filtering or controls are in place there, and it's not uncommon for "open" access points in some places to restrict VPN traffic.  Unless the VPN provider has other ports you can use or try to use, point #3 about "there's no specific way to bypass controls" still applies.